# RunOnUiThread that try to add a TextView crashes

Tags: java, android, multithreading, view

I have a class called Player that create the TextView within an image

```
    public Player(String username, boolean isWhite, Context context){
    this.username = username;
    this.isWhite = isWhite;
    this.context = context;
    label = new TextView(context);
    if(isWhite)
        label.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.white, 0, 0, 0);
    else
        label.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.black, 0, 0, 0);

   label.setText(username);
}
```

And a listener read the message from server

```
public void run(){
    try {
        String[] messages;//ci salvo i messaggi che arrivano
        //PARTITA
        for (messages = ConnectionStream.getIn().readLine().split(":");
             !messages[0].equals("ENDGAME"); messages = ConnectionStream.getIn().readLine().split(":")) {
            switch (messages[0]) {//scelgo cosa fare a seconda del messaggio
                case "ADD"://ADD:NOMEGIOCATORE:NODODIPARTENZA:WHITE/BLACK
                    game.login(messages[1], messages[3].equals("white"));
                    game.movePlayer(game.getPlayer(messages[1]), messages[2]);
                    break;
                case "MOVE"://MOVE:GIOCATORE:NODO
                    game.movePlayer(game.getPlayer(messages[1]), messages[2]);
                    break;
                case "REMOVE"://REMOVE:GIOCATORE
                    game.logout(game.getPlayer(messages[1]));
                    break;
                case "DUEL"://DUEL:GIOCATORENEMICO
                    /*vertexListener.setDueling(true);//finchè duello non posso spostarmi
                    duel = new DuelFrame(frame, messages[1], connectionStream.getOut());
                    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(duel);*/
                    break;
                case "ENDDUEL":
                    /*if(duel!=null)
                        duel.removeDuel();
                    duel = null;
                    vertexListener.setDueling(false);//ora posso spostarmi
                    break;*/
                case "SETBULLETS"://SETBULLETS:INT
                    game.setBullets(Integer.parseInt(messages[1]));
                    break;
                case "ADDBULLETS"://ADDBULLETS:INT
                    game.addBullets(Integer.parseInt(messages[1]));
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception("Server sent weird command: " + messages[0]);
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        game.showError(e.toString());
    }
}
```

When i receive the message MOVE:PLAYER:NODE, the function move(Player player, String node) is called

```
    public void movePlayer(final Player player, String node){
        final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT);
        Point point = nodes.get(node);
        params.leftMargin = point.x;
        params.topMargin = point.y+NODE_HEIGHT;
        final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                layout.addView(player.getLabel(), params);
            }
        });
    }
```

My problem is that runOnUiThread crashes and i can't even know why. I tried to surround it with try-catch and to don't use runOnUiThread (that gave me the exception "Only the owner of the view can touch it"). Is there any way to find the error in this multi-threaded application?

Comment: can you post your logcat?

Comment: I cannot because when my app crashes, it restart by itself and delete my logcat

Comment: Select no filters in your logcat instead of Show only selected application

Comment: I solved the problem by reading the exception thanks to your comment, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that i was trying to add a View that twas already shown and this caused the problem

Answer (score 0):

Run it on a new thread brother. Like below:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            try {

                YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        layout.addView(player.getLabel(), params);
                    }
                });

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("addView_EX", e + "   +++++");
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: Alright, then just try calling the `movePlayer` method inside the thread, where you call the method. And remove the thread inside the method.